# CRONJOB I ve seen and searched the blogs but I am not found nothing

Tags: kubernetes

How to connect A Cron job to Redshift host and S3 bucket?

Expecting Cron job will connect to Redshift hostname and S3 bucket

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, specific question, not tags and your story. You also need to show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what your cronjob is running.  Start by looking into the awscli (for shell level commands) - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/index.html and boto3 (SDK for python connectivity) - https://github.com/boto/boto3.  There are other SDKs available for the software you are running but hopefully these resources will give you a start.  As for Redshift you can connect using the above API calls or by installing/using a jdbc client.

More description on what you are trying to achieve is needed to give you more specific advice.